# “Cross-thread operation is not valid” exception when trying to get value of comboBox in Backgroundworker

Tags: c#, multithreading, combobox

I have some problem when trying to get value of combobox in IF statement in Backgroundworker. When I try to run this code

```
 if (KondisiSaldo.SelectedItem == "Kurang dari...")
 {
   view.RowFilter = string.Format("[Saldo] < '{0}'", thresholdcas);
   view2.RowFilter = string.Format("[Saldo] > '{0}'", thresholdcas);


   this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
   {
     ViewDataSaldoGV.DataSource = view;
     SaldoUnscheduleGV.DataSource = view2;
   }));
}
```

The error says

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'KondisiSaldo' accessed from
>   a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Yes you have to store the value from the form inside a initiated property and then you can call its value from inside the backgroundworker, or pass it in as a parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

Answer (score 4):

You are accessesing `KondisiSaldo` in non GUI thread. Put the `KondisiSaldo` in Invoke block to access it on GUI thread as your did with `view` and `view2` controls.

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
{
   if (KondisiSaldo.SelectedItem == "Kurang dari...")
   {
         view.RowFilter = string.Format("[Saldo] < '{0}'", thresholdcas);
         view2.RowFilter = string.Format("[Saldo] > '{0}'", thresholdcas);   

         ViewDataSaldoGV.DataSource = view;
         SaldoUnscheduleGV.DataSource = view2;
   }
}));
```

You may need to adjust the condition you have.